# Resetting (roll) rotation on a perspective camera with FirstPersonCameraController

Tags: 3d, camera, libgdx

I often position and use `camera.lookAt` on my perspective camera so I am sure how my camera is oriented. However, with a `FirstPersonCameraController` it start to roll when I move the camera from left to right and thus not properly functioning anymore as a `FirstPersonCameraController`. Is there a way to fix this or use the `FirstPersonCameraController` to make the camera look at a specific point to keep it functioning properly? Without using `lookAt` or rotating the camera on both x and y axis the `FirstPersonCameraController` functions properly, so I guess it is just a by product from working on a already rotated camera.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing the last line of the question I fixed the issue, still posting to help others.

I figured I reset the up vector of the camera. I guess the `FirstPersonCameraController` uses this to calculate rotation. So after rotating the camera (or using `lookAt`):

```
camera.up.set(0, 1, 0);
```

Thanks for being my [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) once again stackoverflow.